# How to launch a mobile app from another app?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there any way to launch for one mobile app to launch another mobile app, e.g. via a button click?

Example: the `org.apache.cordova.camera` plugin allows direct access to the camera on a button click.  In the same way, how can one app launch another app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name here");
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

If you don't know the package name of application that you want to launch then try this

```
PackageManager pm;
pm = getPackageManager();
//  get a list of all installed apps then launch by pakagename.
packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

String packagename = packages.get(position).packageName.toString()
```

Refer this [**android-package-manager**](http://android-dev-sagarg.blogspot.in/2013/08/use-of-android-package-manager-for.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this java code:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("appPackage");
this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

or try any of these 2 plugins for launching apps:

- https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp
- https://github.com/dmedvinsky/cordova-startapp

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out full name of application, and then start it as activity via intent like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), "full name of activity you are starting");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

You can even receive result from that activity check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result). Hope this helps!